# Ansible: passing special characters in echo into realm join command

Tags: ansible

I'm having a problem with my ansible playbook.  Anyone know the solution?

```
- name: add to domain
  shell: |
    echo "{{pass}}" | realm join {{DOMAIN}} -U {{user}}
```

command is:

```
ansible-playbook server -i hosts -e domain=domain.net -e user=username@DOMAIN.NET -e pass='"pass!23$"'
```

It seems like the problem is in the echo "{{pass}}" portion.

Comment: According [Automate a domain join on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563459/266568) and [Join domain with Red Hat 7 and without prompting the password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424294/266568) it looks like the correct approach at a first glance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the result and take a look at the details. For example, the play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - shell: >-
      echo '{{ pass }} {{ domain }} {{ user }}' | awk '{print}'
    register: out
  - debug:
      var: out
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e domain=domain.net -e user=username@DOMAIN.NET -e pass='pass!23$' pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [shell] **********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out:
    ansible_facts:
      discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3
    changed: true
    cmd: echo 'pass!23$ domain.net username@DOMAIN.NET' | awk '{print}'
    delta: '0:00:00.005417'
    end: '2023-04-25 16:49:16.623025'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-04-25 16:49:16.617608'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: pass!23$ domain.net username@DOMAIN.NET
    stdout_lines:
    - pass!23$ domain.net username@DOMAIN.NET

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Yes.  I get the same thing too.  it works as expected.  I did notice when I try to do the realm join command itself on the server by echo'ing the password in, it doesn't work.  without the echo, it works just fine.  maybe it just doesn't like the echo method.

Comment: Try [stdin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-stdin).